# Worklight Optimization

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Worklight 5.0.61 on a Liberty Server. We are utilizing JQuery Mobile library. We have PNG Crushed all of our images. 
Our app (on both iOS and Android) takes about a minute to load every single time the app opens.  There may be a slight decrease in the amount of time to load for subsequent launches. But not a noticeable decrease.

Every time the app launches, The app shows a black page for a minute and then loads the splash screen.  We're getting complaints that the app isn't working because people are impatient waiting for it to load.  Are there any other steps I can take to decrease the black screen load time? Or is there anyway to show the splash screen during that initial black screen?
Currently, the splash screen is being loaded in the onCreate method of the java file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Based on your edit. Try with Worklight 5.0.6.2 and come back with results*

---

1) The Minification and Concatenation feature works **only** on the Mobile Web and Desktop Browser page. [This is clearly stated in the user documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_building_and_deploying_build_settings_deploy_target.html).

This feature will hold no effect on your application's file size in iOS and Android.

See this question for options: [IBM Worklight - Filesize of the generated Android project's .apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800964/ibm-worklight-filesize-of-the-generated-android-projects-apk)

The above will help in lowering the *file size* of the application. This can affect performance as well, depending on the below. It will vary based on complexity, device, etc...

These include:

- Remove dead code
- Make sure your code is not bloated
- PNGCrush your images
- Don't include files you do not need (.js, .css, .whatever)
- Use Google Closure (carefully). [See also this blog post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/obfuscating_javascript_code?lang=en) about using Closure

2) You do not mention critical and required information in order to *answer* your question

- What is your Worklight version?
- Is this related only to the application's FIRST launch, or ANY launch?
- Are you using any library, such as jQuery Mobile or Dojo?
- What is the app actually doing on startup? loads only web resources? invokes any adapter procedures and waits for data to return and be processed? anything else?

You may try with Worklight 5.0.6.2, 6.0.0.2 or 6.1.0.1, all three now containing fixes to enhance the load time of an application the first time it launches.

Please edit your question with something useful to work with.